# Checking custom URLs and user IDs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Is there a better way to do this? I'm kinda ending up having a lot of `if` statements.

```
if params[:custom_url] || params[:user_id]
    if !params[:user_id].blank?
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id]).first
      @url = @user.custom_url
    else
      @url = params[:custom_url]
      @user = User.where(:custom_url => @url).first
    end
end
```

Comment: instead of `!params[:user_id].blank?`, you can write `params[:user_id].present?` which reads more nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big fan of `case..when`:

```
@user = User.find_first(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
@user ||= User.find_by_custom_url(@url)

@url = params[:custom_url] || @user.custom_url
```

Comment: At line 2, @url is going to be nil, so there's no sense using it as a param.

Comment: Line 1, wouldn't it be better to use `if params[:user_id].present?`

Answer (score 1):

I typically chain scopes together like this:

Model:

```
def self.by_user_and_url(user_id, custom_url)
  by_user(user_id).by_custom_url(custom_url)
end

def self.by_user(user_id)
  user_id ? where(user_id: user_id) : scoped
end

def self.by_custom_url(custom_url)
  custom_url ? where(custom_url: custom_url) : scoped
end
```

Controller:

```
if params[:custom_url].present? || params[:user_id].present?
  @user = User.by_user_and_url(params[:user_id], params[:custom_url]).first
end
```

I'm not sure why you had two instance variables.  The url can be pulled from the @user instance variable if you need it in your view.